# What does "Do you think" mean in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning

A Conversation Between a Robot and a Human

Robot: Oh, Frankie.

Woman: Oh, oh, look what you made me do.

Robot: What?

Woman: You made me prick my finger. Oh, I wish you wouldn't keep doing that. I hate being slapped on the back all the time. You don't know your strength.

Robot: Umm, oh!

Woman: What's the matter?

Robot: What's that red stuff on your finger?

Woman: Blood. My finger was pricked by the needle.

Robot: Oh, oh, oh,oh, oh, ...

Woman: Oh, don't say you're going to faint. I've heard of people fainting at the sight of blood, but robots fainting!

Robot: Oh, maybe I'm really becoming a person now. **Do you think**?

Woman: Maybe, you never know. Mm, could you give me that iodine to put on my finger? It's the yellow stuff in the cupboard.

Robot: Iodine, OK.

---

What does "**Do you think**?" mean in this sentence?

Is it short form of "**What** do you think"?

Comment: It means *Do you agree* with my previous statement.  The two sentences could be rewritten as one.  *Do you think that maybe I'm really becoming a person now?*